# Failing to call spring bean from portlet

Tags: spring, liferay, liferay-6, spring-jdbc

I have Spring bean as below:

```
    @Service("bookService")
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("bookDao")
    private BookDao bookDao;
```

i have a portlet trying access it as below:

```
   62   public BookService getBookService() {
63      ApplicationContext springCtx =   PortletApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getPortletContext());
64      return (BookService)springCtx.getBean("bookService");
    }


but i have the below nullpointer exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at chapter09.code.listing.base.BookCatalogPortlet.getBookService(BookCatalogPortlet.java:64)
at chapter09.code.listing.base.BookCatalogPortlet.init(BookCatalogPortlet.java:59)
```

Please let me know if i am missing some thing
source available @http://portletsinaction.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ch9_BookCatalogSpringJdbc/

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Can you provide the link to the project which you are trying to deploy? Also, please try to format your question properly from next time onwards. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its issue with Liferay 6.1.1 
I have tested the same with 6.0.6 and its working fine.